# GREP rule to catch all types of web link / URL

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I'm looking to build a robust, reliable GREP rule to catch all web links and URLs that appears in text, covering all possible characters and gotchas like HTTPS, or URLs in brackets like (http://whatever.com), or followed by punctuation like http://whatever.com?! It's for an InDesign paragraph style GREP rule.

I've put the best I've come up with so far down below as an answer - is it missing anything, is there anything more robust or straightforward?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work pretty well:

```
https?\://.*?(?=(\)|\.|\,|\?|\!|"|')*($|\s))
```

- Start with either http:// or https://

  - `https?\://`
- ...then match the shortest uninterrupted string of *any* characters 
  -`.*?`
- ...that is followed by, but doesn't include

  - the `(?=` `)` "positive lookahead"
- ...zero or more of any common punctuation - `)` `.` `,` `?` `!` and any type of single or double quotation mark, curly or straight, left or right

  - `(\)|\.|\,|\?|\!|"|')*`
- ...and then either the end of the paragraph or any type of whitespace

  - `($|\s)`

Some testing:

[image]

Comment: If I use this in notepad++ with the source code for this webpage, I see that you need figure out how to stop on less-than/greater-than brackets, and this will grab "http://" without an actual url. This seems to capture most instances with no false positives (just slightly greedy when there are brackets), though I haven't looked for false negatives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex